# LWC Lightning-Record-View-form behavior on Lookup Fields (Display Name Vs ID hyperlinks)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordviewform

I'm using lightning Record view form in LWC to display OwnerID of account. Some users are seeing hyperlink with Owner Name and some users are seeing hyperlink with SalesforceID. What could be the reason ? I am not able to pinpoint the issue since it's a standard field with default read access to all users.

Comment: Do you have User Sharing enabled? What happens if the user with an ID clicks on the link?

Comment: @sfdxfox I have figured it out. The issue seems to be with the lookup field not being visible on the page Layout for some of the users. If they have lookup field on pagelayout --> Name is displayed, if not just ID is displayed. Maybe that's how they designed view form by using UI api.

Comment: Add these fields on the page layout for the relevant record type.